# Limit the size of the gesture detector in the draggable widget

Tags: flutter, draggable

I am building a list view that is populated by draggle widgets, I would like only a subsection of the draggable to in-fact be draggable and pass gestures on the rest of the widget through to the list view below, however I would like the whole widget to move. Im hoping for a widget that looks as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/greR2.jpg
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a hacky way to put this together but have you considered these options yet?

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_reorderable_list

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/reorderable_list.dart